# ANT Keeps saying "Wrong JAVA version"

Tags: java, xml, ant

I recently installed ANT and it's my first time using it. The problem is that it keeps saying "Wrong Java Compiler Version Installed" whereas I have JDK 1.8.0_51 installed. Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? I've set the environment variable to point to the jdk folder and not the jre one or the bin directory. Any solutions? Here's the screenshot of the error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/suyNN.jpg

Here's the xml file

https://www.dropbox.com/s/oh3tg12hkzd901m/build.xml?dl=0

```
<project name="ss7.release.sf" default="package" basedir=".">
    <!--  Components Versions  -->
    <property name="release.version" value="2.1.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property name="ss7.version" value="2.1.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property name="asn.version" value="2.0.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property name="sctp.version" value="1.1.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property name="stream.version" value="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property name="protocols.build.list" value="parent,m3ua,mtp,isup,sccp,tcap,map"/>
    <property name="protocols.copy.list" value="m3ua,mtp,isup,sccp,tcap,map"/>
    <!--  Directories Configuration  -->
    <property name="checkout.basedir" value="checkout"/>
    <property name="zip.dir" value="${basedir}/zip"/>
    <property name="zip.file.destination.dir" value="${basedir}/upload"/>
    <property name="zip.file.name" value="mobicents-ss7-${release.version}"/>
    <property name="failoncopy" value="true"/>
    <property name="test.skip" value="true"/>
    <!--  Definition  -->
    <property name="release.name" value="SNAPSHOT"/>
    <property environment="sys"/>
    <condition property="mvn.executable" value="${sys.M2_HOME}\bin\mvn.bat" else="mvn">
        <os family="windows"/>
    </condition>
    <taskdef onerror="fail" resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${ss7.release.sf}/../ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>
    <target name="init">
        <echo message="Java Version: ${java.version}"/>
        <echo message="Java home: ${java.home}"/>
        <fail message="Unsupported Java version: ${java.version}. Make sure that the version of the Java compiler is 1.7 (7.0) or greater.">
            <condition>
                <not>
                    <or>
                        <contains string="${java.version}" substring="1.7" casesensitive="false"/>
                    </or>
                </not>
            </condition>
        </fail>
    </target>
    <target name="checkout" description="Checks out src and downloads everything that is required." depends="checkout-sources"/>
    <target name="build" description="Builds components sources and everything associated." depends="build-sources-commons,build-sources-sctp,build-sources-asn,build-sources-stream,build-sources-ss7"/>
    <target name="copy" depends="copy-asn,copy-sctp,copy-protocols-ss7"/>
    <target name="package" description="Builds builds binary package." depends="init,clean,checkout,zip.src,build,notes,copy,zip.binary"/>
    <target name="clean">
        <echo>Cleaning checkout directory</echo>
        <delete dir="${ant.file.ss7.release.sf}/../${checkout.basedir}" verbose="false"/>
        <echo>Cleaning work directory</echo>
        <delete dir="${zip.dir}" verbose="false"/>
        <echo>Cleaning upload directory</echo>
        <delete dir="${zip.file.destination.dir}" verbose="false"/>
    </target>
    <target name="checkout-sources">
        <echo>Checking out sources</echo>
        <mkdir dir="${checkout.basedir}"/>
        <exec executable="${mvn.executable}" dir="${ant.file.mobicents.release}/../">
            <arg line="validate -P checkout -Dcheckout.dir=${checkout.basedir}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <target name="build-sources-commons">
        <exec executable="${mvn.executable}" dir="${checkout.basedir}/commons">
            <arg line="install -P release,set-svn-revision -Dmaven.test.skip=${test.skip} -Drelease.name=${release.name}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <target name="build-sources-sctp">
        <exec executable="${mvn.executable}" dir="${checkout.basedir}/sctp">
            <arg line="install -P release,set-svn-revision -Dmaven.test.skip=${test.skip} -Drelease.name=${release.name}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <target name="build-sources-asn">
        <exec executable="${mvn.executable}" dir="${checkout.basedir}/asn">
            <arg line="install -Prelease,set-svn-revision -Dmaven.test.skip=${test.skip} -Drelease.name=${release.name}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <target name="build-sources-stream">
        <exec executable="${mvn.executable}" dir="${checkout.basedir}/stream">
            <arg line="install -P release,set-svn-revision -Dmaven.test.skip=${test.skip} -Drelease.name=${release.name}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <target name="build-sources-ss7">
        <echo>Build SS7</echo>
        <exec executable="${mvn.executable}" dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7">
            <arg line="-f pom.xml install -P release,set-svn-revision -Dmaven.test.skip=${test.skip} -Drelease.name=${release.name}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
    <target name="notes">
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}" file="${basedir}/README.TXT" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <filterchain>
                <replacetokens>
                    <token key="VERSION" value="${release.version}"/>
                    <token key="SCTP_VERSION" value="${sctp.version}"/>
                    <token key="ASN_VERSION" value="${asn.version}"/>
                    <token key="STREAM_VERSION" value="${stream.version}"/>
                    <token key="SS7_VERSION" value="${ss7.version}"/>
                </replacetokens>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="copy-asn">
        <echo>Copy ASN</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/asn" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/asn/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy ASN Docs</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/asn/docs" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/asn/docs/jdocbook-mobicents/target/docbook/publish">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="copy-sctp">
        <echo>Copy SCTP</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/sctp" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/sctp/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy SCTP Docs</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/sctp/docs" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/sctp/docs/jdocbook-mobicents/target/docbook/publish">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="copy-stream">
        <echo>Copy Stream</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/stream" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/stream/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <target name="copy-protocols-ss7">
        <echo>Copy SS7 Service</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/mobicents-ss7-service" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/service/target/mobicents-ss7-service">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy sgw</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/mobicents-sgw" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/sgw/boot/target/mobicents-sgw">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy SS7 Simulator</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/mobicents-ss7-simulator" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/tools/simulator/bootstrap/target/simulator-ss7">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy Protocols</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/protocols" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/tcap/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/map/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/isup/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/cap/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/inap/release/${release.name}">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy Shell</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/shell/lib" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/management/shell-client/target/mobicents-cli/lib">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/shell/bin" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/management/shell-client/target/mobicents-cli/bin">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <copy file="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/hardware/cli/target/linkset-cli.jar" todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/shell/lib" failonerror="${failoncopy}"/>
        <copy file="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/m3ua/cli/m3ua/target/m3ua-cli-m3ua.jar" todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/shell/lib" failonerror="${failoncopy}"/>
        <copy file="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/m3ua/cli/sctp/target/m3ua-cli-sctp.jar" todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/shell/lib" failonerror="${failoncopy}"/>
        <copy file="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/sccp/sccp-cli/target/sccp-cli.jar" todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/shell/lib" failonerror="${failoncopy}"/>
        <echo>Copy Native</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/native" failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/hardware/dahdi/native/linux/target">
                <include name="*.so"/>
            </fileset>
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/hardware/dialogic/native/linux/target">
                <include name="*.so"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy Docs</echo>
        <copy todir="${zip.dir}/ss7/docs" failonerror="${failoncopy}">
            <fileset dir="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/docs/jdocbook-mobicents/target/docbook/publish">
                <include name="**"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
        <echo>Copy Build File</echo>
        <copy file="${checkout.basedir}/ss7/release/release-build.xml" tofile="${zip.dir}/ss7/build.xml" failonerror="${failoncopy}"/>
    </target>
    <target name="zip.binary">
        <zip destfile="${zip.file.destination.dir}/${zip.file.name}.zip">
            <zipfileset dir="${zip.dir}" excludes="zip"></zipfileset>
        </zip>
        <antcall target="checksum">
            <param name="source.file" value="${zip.file.destination.dir}/${zip.file.name}.zip"/>
            <param name="algorithm" value="sha1"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>
    <target name="zip.src">
        <mkdir dir="${zip.file.destination.dir}"/>
        <zip destfile="${zip.file.destination.dir}/${zip.file.name}-src.zip">
            <zipfileset dir="${checkout.basedir}" excludes="zip"></zipfileset>
        </zip>
        <antcall target="checksum">
            <param name="source.file" value="${zip.file.destination.dir}/${zip.file.name}-src.zip"/>
            <param name="algorithm" value="sha1"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>
    <target name="checksum">
        <checksum file="${source.file}" algorithm="${algorithm}" fileext=".${algorithm}.asc" forceOverwrite="yes"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you checked line 42 in build.xml?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam https://www.dropbox.com/s/oh3tg12hkzd901m/build.xml?dl=0

Comment: @stardamore please add it to the question instead of dropbox

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam Done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `init` target, you're explicitly telling Ant to fail the build when the Java installation is not 1.7. Try including 1.8 in the condition:

```
<target name="init">
   <echo message="Java Version: ${java.version}"/>
   <echo message="Java home: ${java.home}"/>
   <fail message="Unsupported Java version: ${java.version}. Make sure that the version of the Java compiler is 1.7 (7.0) or greater.">
     <condition>
      <not>
         <or>
           <contains string="${java.version}" substring="1.7" casesensitive="false"/>
           <contains string="${java.version}" substring="1.8" casesensitive="false"/>
         </or>
      </not>
     </condition>
   </fail>
</target>
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks loads!